# How to stop my program from eternally waiting? (wait/notify multithreading issue)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have three classes, one that is meant to represent a pile of urls

```
    private Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();

    public Queue<String> getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    private int limit = 5;
    private int stillParsing;

    public synchronized String getNextString() throws InterruptedException {
        while (queue.isEmpty()||stillParsing > limit) {
            System.out.println("no for you "+ queue.peek());
            wait();
        }

        System.out.println("grabbed");

        notify();
        stillParsing++;
        System.out.println(queue.peek());
        return queue.remove();

    }

    public synchronized void doneParsing() {
        stillParsing--;
    }

}
```

A thread class whose run method is

```
public void run(){
        try {
        sleep(30);
        for(;;){

              String currenturl = pile.getNextString();
              //(do things)
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            pile.doneParsing();
        }
    }
```

And a mapper that actually adds objects into the pile of urls using this snipet

```
while (urls.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try{

                    word.set(urls.nextToken());
                String currenturl = word.toString();
                System.out.println(currenturl);
                pile.getQueue().add(currenturl);
```

From debugging what I think happens is that all of the threads try to get from the queue at once before the mapper has a chance to populate it and they get stuck waiting.  Unfortunately all of the threads waiting is causing my program to hang up and not add more urls to the queue.  How should I go about taking care of this issue?  Preferably while still using wait notify.

Comment: You are correct. Use a concurrent queue. Java gives you all the tools you need to do things like this in the `java.util.concurrent`package.

Comment: Are you able to use a `BlockingQueue` instead of a `Queue`?

Comment: Possibly, still I'd like to know why what I have is not working.

Comment: Your code isn't thread-safe to begin with as you're exposing the `queue` via `getQueue()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (urls.hasMoreTokens()) {
    try {
       word.set(urls.nextToken());
       String currenturl = word.toString();
       System.out.println(currenturl);
       pile.getQueue().add(currenturl);
```

In the above code, you're breaking the encapsulation of the pile by adding something to its queue without going though a method of the pile. You should not have a `getQueue()` method in this class: all the accesses to this shared data structure should be synchronized on the same lock. You should thus add a synchronized method allowing to add a URL to the queue. And this method should also call `notify()` (or better: `notifyAll()`), in order to wake up the threads that are waiting for some element to be in the queue:

```
public synchronized void addUrl(String url) {
    queue.add(url);
    notifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even without reading all lines of your code and explanations I can say that your usage of wait and notify are buggy.

Method `wait()` is blocking. It exits only when `notify()` on the same monitor is called. This means that you cannot put both `wait()` and `notify()` from the same thread. You simply never arrive to `notify()` because `wait()` is blocked forever.

Other version of `wait()`: `wait(timeout)` is blocked but is limited by specified timeout. 
Moreover wait/notify pair work only if they are written into `synchronized` block:

```
// thread-1
synchronoized(obj) {
    obj.wait();
} 


// thread-2
synchronoized(obj) {
    obj.notify();
}
```

Thread-1 will exit wait when thread-2 calls notify.

Comment: In addition, `notify` is rarely correct -- `notifyAll` is typically what's required for correctness to prevent wakeups from being swallowed.

Comment: @Tom G, it depends on your application. Often you want to awake only one thread.

Comment: Let me rephrase -- using `notify` requires extra care, because you don't control which thread is awoken and it requires extra work to make sure only the correct thread can acquire the object's monitor.